# Identify machine configuration via code

Tags: linux, cpu

I am writing a program where I need to know about the machine configuration. Code will run on Linux. I want to find the following:

1. Number of CPU Cores
2. Number of CPU Sockets
3. Number of Disks
4. If it's a 4 socket processor then which 2 sockets are adjacent to each other

Does Linux expose this information in some file that I can read in to get this information?

What are some good resources to read about such linux internals?

Comment: `dmidecode`, `lshw`, `lscpu`, `lsblk`, `inxi` ...

Answer (score 2):

```
Does Linux expose this information in some file that I can read in to get this information?

1. Number of CPU Cores
2. Number of CPU Sockets
3. Number of Disks
4. If it's a 4 socket processor then which 2 sockets are adjacent to each other
```

Yes, information about `CPUs` and `Disks` is available in Linux.

`/proc/cpuinfo` contains detailed information about the `CPU`.

```
e.g. cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

The command `sudo fdisk -l` provides a listing of disks and their related information.

This [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146051/number-of-processors-in-proc-cpuinfo) provides some specifics regarding `/proc/cpuinfo`.

This [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/) explains the usage and output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: Agreed /proc/cpuinfo is a good place to look for info about CPUs, but user855 asked about disks - `lsblk` is a better option for that. Where to look for info? tldp, google, /usr/share/doc