# Understanding the output of /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, cpu, arm

I have a [LeMaker HiKey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019O3QTSA) development board. I purchased it for testing a couple of libraries on ARM64 cpu architecture. The board provides two Cortex-A53 processors, provides eight cores, and uses Linaro Linux:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hikey 3.18.0-linaro-hikey #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 30 00:11:03 UTC 2015
aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I observed the self tests are running a little slower than expected, so I'm mildly investigating it. I also noticed a *`cat`* of `/proc/cpuinfo` is returning something that does not look quite right, but I'm not sure if its cause for concern. It does not look quite right to me because I used to seeing cpu information present for each core (something like shown in [Number of processors in /proc/cpuinfo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146051)).

Does the output of `/proc/cpuinfo` indicate a problem with the board or its configuration? Or is this output expected with some dev boards?

---

***ARM Cortex A53 (octa-core)***:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Processor   : AArch64 Processor rev 3 (aarch64)
processor   : 0
processor   : 1
processor   : 2
processor   : 3
processor   : 4
processor   : 5
processor   : 6
processor   : 7
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: AArch64
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : HiKey Development Board
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the expected output to Arm based processors. All Serialized cores are shown in list with line breaks instead of separated processors. Features are evaluated by [cpuinfo](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm64/kernel/cpuinfo.c?v=3.18) code, and only show if all cores support them

```
         /*
          * Mismatched CPU features are a recipe for disaster. Don't even
          * pretend to support them.
          */
         WARN_TAINT_ONCE(diff, TAINT_CPU_OUT_OF_SPEC,
                         "Unsupported CPU feature variation.");
```

The other variables are:

- `CPU implementer:` Your code means ARM;
- `CPU architecture:` AArch64 means 64 bit ARM board:
- `CPU variant :` Indicates the variant number of the processor, or "major revision". Yours is zero.
- `CPU part:` Part number. `0xd03` indicates Cortex-A53 processor.
- `CPU revision:` Indicates patch release or "minor revision". 3, in your case
- `Hardware    : HiKey Development Board` is self explanatory

If you want to check your processor max clock, just type `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq`. To check the current clock `dmidecode | grep "Current Speed"` should do the trick.

Another thing that could impact the performance of your processor is the [cpu governor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) you are using. Maybe setting the performance one could be better for your needs:

```
cpupower frequency-set -g performance
```

**Documentation:**

- [Arm Information](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337h/Cihhbddh.html)
- [How to understand the information of my android processor [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775982/how-to-understand-the-information-of-my-android-processor)
- [arm64: restore bogomips information in /proc/cpuinfo](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2015-November/386247.html)